# How to use WebService Class (NOT WCF) - .NET

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, .net-4.0, wsdl

Before I start, I dont want to use WCF because of this outstanding issue Im experiencing - I want to explore other options:

[Issue connecting to Server from WCF Client - HTTPS endpoint - Works on Local Dev but not Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790009/issue-connecting-to-server-from-wcf-client-https-endpoint-works-on-local-dev)

Now I have manually created some proxy classes based off a third parties WSDL, using:

1. disco.exe (.discomap)
2. wsdl to create the proxy classes

Now I couldnt use **Add Web Reference** because of this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793078/the-html-document-does-not-contain-web-service-discovery-information), so I created them manually as instructed. Now wdsl has created the **XtkSession.cs** - I have tried using its Logon method and I get a **SoapHeaderException** exception. When I list the exeption to the screen it is empty - Am i doing something wrong? This is a Console App which I want to call an external thirdparty webservice using SOAP.

```
    try
    {
        XtkSession WebLogon = new XtkSession();
        WebLogon.Url = "https://logon.net/soaprouter.jsp";
        var response = adobeWebLogon.Logon(null, "userName", "passWord", element,
                                                                        out sessionInfo, out securityToken);

        Screen.WriteLineToScreen("Web Response       : " + response);
        Screen.WriteLineToScreen("Web Security Token : " + securityToken);
    }
    catch (SoapHeaderException ex)
    {
        Screen.WriteLineToScreen("SoapHeaderException : " + " Actor: " + ex.Actor
                                                          + " Code : " + ex.Code
                                                          + " Detail: " + ex.Detail
                                                          + " Inner : " + ex.InnerException);
    }
```

Comment: If you're using WSDL to generate the proxy classes, you're still using WCF

Comment: So there is no way of NOT using wcf in .net for sending a soap xml payload? Is the web reference bit for IIS hosted services only?

Comment: Another way is to  write code to handler the HTTP requests/response, which means you implement everything from scratch and needs a lot effort. Problem you should just figure out the WCF problem.

Comment: Cheers Matt - it's a head scratcher. Off to bed and will get fiddler configured for the wcf problem tomorrow  thanks for taking the time.