# New-WebServiceProxy fails with InvalidOperationException

Tags: powershell, soap, wsdl

I'm attempting to port a working SOAP client (written in Perl) to PowerShell for a different client (who won't allow us to pollute their locked-down windows environment with Perl).

So I try and download the WSDL information to create a proxy, using examples I found on the Web. This is how the existing Perl Code works, so the approach is sound.

`$soap = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url -UseDefaultCredential`

```
New-WebServiceProxy : The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
At line:1 char:9
+ $soap = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (http://localhos...sx:Uri) [New-WebServiceProxy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
```

But, as I said, this is based on working code, so it is unlikely anything is wrong at the server end. As a test, type

`$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredential $url`

`$WebResponse`

And I get:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                    <!-- SOAP API definitions -->
                    <definitions name="SOAPAPI"
```

Which is what I would expect - it's start of the header of the WSDL.

I'm not seeing what's going wrong, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: A stab in the dark: does adding `?wsdl` to the value of `$uri` help?

Comment: In this case, no. We know the uri is correct - it is what is generated by the existing Perl code, and we get the WSDL back as content in the Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: Is your variable $uri or $url? The error is different from your code

Comment: Have you looked at this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793078/the-html-document-does-not-contain-web-service-discovery-information

Comment: sorry, there's a typo there. The variable is $url, and it is conisitent in my PS history.

Comment: I looked at that article. I don't control the application generating the WSDL, and it doesn't follow the ?wsdl convention (because it has an extensive CGI and more than one SOAP API), so no soap (pun intended)

Comment: I tried dumping the content from `$WebResponse` into a file, and feeding that to `New-WebServiceProxy`, but it fails to validate the XML.I seem to have a strange UTF BOM at the start of the output I can't get rid of, and I wonder if this is what is crashing `New-WebServiceProxy` if I download the WSDL directly. In the Perl case, LWP::UserAgent and SOAP::Lite may be convering the sins of the IIS, so it isn't a problem. I have verified the Perl Code still runs correctly, btw.

Comment: The BOM is FF FE EF 00 BB 00 BF 00. a 16 bit little endian (UNICODE encoding) of a UTF8 BOM (FEFF EFBBBF)?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that there's no-one who actually **understands** what `New-WebServiceProxy` does. Here's a more detailed message (via the `$_ | ConvertTo-Json` hack): `The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.` I have tried this with both Windows and Linux servers. If I manually put the wsdl in a Here string, set the endpoint, and write that to a local file the cmdlet works. Wireshark tells me the WSDL was downloaded successfully, so why can't the cmdlet process it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - give up. It doesn't work. As a workaround, download the WSDL using Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile (that's important) and invoke New-Webserviceproxy with a local file Uri. If you need authentication, set the Credentials or UseDefaultCredentials property manually as appropriate (setting the parameters to New-Webserviceproxy does not have any effect). It now works, but I have to conclude that the underlying .Net c# code was never tested with anything but MS services....

Anyway, this was the solution:

```bsh
        <#
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
        Phase 1: Download the service description (WSDL)

        We ought to be able to simply invoke the New-WebProxyService cmdlet with
        the URI of the service description, but that consistently fails, possibly because
        this is not a .Net application.

        So the workaround is to download the service description to a temporary file, and
        load that in New-WebServiceProxy as a file::/// URI
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    #>

        $tmp = New-TemporaryFile
        $tmpName = $tmp.FullName

        # Splatting all the parameters to the cmdlet is more readable than a mix of command line
        # and splatted parameters 
        $wsdlArgs = @{
            Uri = -join ($uri,'?trid=', $service)
            OutFile = $tmpName
            PassThru = $true
            ErrorAction = 'Stop'
        }
        if ($Credential -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
            $wsdlArgs['UseDefaultCredentials'] = $true
        }
        else {
            $wsdlArgs['Credential'] = $Credential
        }
        $wsdlResponse = Invoke-WebRequest @wsdlArgs # No try/catch here - if it fails, we fail!

    <#
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
        Phase 2: Create a WebServiceProxy Object

        We use try {} / finally {} to ensure that whether our cmdlet succeeds or fails,
        we clean up our mess...
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    #>

        # Splatting all the parameters to the cmdlet is more readable than a mix of command line
        # and splatted parameters 
        $soapArgs = @{
            Uri         = ([System.Uri]($tmpName)).AbsoluteUri
            Class       = 'SOAPAPI'
            Namespace   = "www.kambe.com.au"
            ErrorAction = 'Stop'
        }
        try {
            $soap = New-WebServiceProxy @soapArgs # No catch block, if the cmdlet fails, we fail!
        }
        finally { # Whether the cmdlet succeeds or fails, we remove the temp file
            Remove-Item $tmpName -Force
        }

        # It seems the Credential and UseDefaultCredential params are ignored by New-WebServiceProxy if not used?
        # Programming pragmatism: it works this way, and not any other way
        if ($Credential -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
            $soap.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
        }
        else {
            $soap.Credentials = $Credential
        }
```